# What is the difference between passing this.state to produce and not? Immer.js

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability, react-state, immer.js

What is the difference between:

`this.setState(produce((draft) => { draft.name ='name'}`

and

`this.setState(produce(this.state, (draft) => { draft.name ='name'}`

can someone explain me this?

Comment: `this.state` is not a function, why would you try to call it?

Comment: I saw this - const nextState = produce(baseState, draft => {
    draft[1].done = true
    draft.push({title: "Tweet about it"})
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases both would act the same

1. `produce((draft) => { draft.name ='name'})` returns a function that wraps argument with a Proxy and applies the mutation. `setState` allows developer to pass a function that will be called with current state.
2. `produce(this.state, (draft) => { draft.name ='name'})` returns the result of applying mutation to a Proxy of the first argument. `setState` allows to pass "updated state" thus it will also work.

The first approach is preferable because of the following

1. If called rapidly in sequence you usually want next state to be built on top of the mutated previous state (famous counter example). And mutation function version of `setState` is the way to go.
2. It is less characters to type.